# Status bar turning black after hidding statusbar in react native (android)

Tags: android, react-native

I want to hide statusbar and go full screen in android. I tried following code but i made status bar totally black.

```
<StatusBar hidden />
<StatusBar hidden={true} />
```

```
StatusBar.setHidden(true);
```

All of them turned statusbar black, check attachment!

[image: Screenshot]

I am using react-navigation/native-stack

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, could you find the solution?

Comment: Same issue so much time later